# Stop queue creation using AMQP through yml file in spring cloud java application

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

[image]

Queue creation is happening using below properties in yml file in springboot application. I need to stop queue creation in rabbitmq. I used autoBindDlq: false, so it stopped creating dlq queue when I ran application but queue creation is happening. I searched and seen declareExchange: false, queueNameGroupOnly: false propeties helps me to stop queue creation, but it could not helped me out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See `RabbitExchangeQueueProvisioner` and you will see that the queue is only declared if the `bindQueue` property is `true`.

Run in a debugger and put a breakpoint in `doProvisionConsumerDestination()` to see what's happening.